# Show there exists a linear operator $L: \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ satisfying $L(v)=-v$ and $L(v_i) = v_i$ for $i = 1,\ldots, m-1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ denote a subspace of $\mathbb R^m$ of dimension $1$.

I've shown that $\dim \bar S = m-1$.

Now suppose $\{v\}$ is a basis for $S$ and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{m-1}\}$ is a basis for $\bar S$.

I've shown that $\{v, v_1, \ldots, v_{m-1}\} $ is a basis for $\mathbb R^m$.

**However I cannot show:**

There exists a linear operator $L: \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ satisfying $L(v)=-v$ and $L(v_i) = v_i$ for $i = 1,\ldots, m-1$.

Also that $L$ corresponds geometrically to a reflection in $\bar S$.

I've considered the linear transformation $P_{\bar S}(v)$ satisfying $v = P_{\bar S}(v) + w$ with $P_{\bar S}(v) \in \bar S$ and $w \in S$. But then I get $P_{\bar S}(v_i) = v_i$ and $P_{\bar S}(v) = v$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a linear transformation is uniquely determined by its action on a base. You already proved $\{v,v_1 ,\cdots, v_{m-1}\}$ is a basis, so you are free to choose where they are mapped to, i.e., $L(v)=-v$ and $L(v_i)=v_i$, and it then extends uniquely to a linear transformation $L:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R ^m$.

Comment: Thanks Ittay. But should't I still prove that $L$ defined this way is a linear transformation ? Also why is $L$ a reflexion ?

Comment: Ittay, could you give me a hint on how to show that the matrix representation for $L$ in the standard basis is $I - \frac 2 {||v||^2}vv^T$ ? I cannot compute it as $[L(e_1),\ldots,L(e_n)]$.